# How to delete all duplicates of a file linked by CoW on BTRFS

Tags: backup, filesystems, btrfs, deduplication

The glory of Copy-on-Write (CoW) allows us to copy a file as many times as we like, without duplicating the used space.

I have used this functionality extensively (as well as manual deduplication of files -- bees, bedup, and rmlint) on a drive I use for backups. I now have many directories with lots of data, which share many files in common with each other.

Using baobab I can search for big files on this drive, to try to prune some big old files, in an effort to tidy everything up, and make room for new backups. The problem is that in most cases, deleting one big file most probably won't free up any space because it's extents are also being used by another copy of the file.

If I find a certain file, and determine to delete it, I would like to remove all copies of it, as I am no longer interested in keeping any copy of it.

More generally, if I want to remove a complete folder from my backups, I would like all copies of the contained files to be remove, from any and every other folder they might be contained in.

**How can I delete complete directories in BTRFS, and have all copies of the contained files removed**

I have checked the man for "rm", but there's no option similar to what is needed in these cases.

[This other question](https://superuser.com/questions/863588/how-to-delete-a-file-in-all-snapshots-on-a-btrfs-system) asks something similar, but focuses on the problem of read-only snapshots, which is not an normally issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) in your question. This is what you wrote:

> If I find a certain file, and determine to delete it, I would like to remove all copies of it, as I am no longer interested in keeping any copy of it.

Since you are no longer interested in keeping any copy of the file, it doesn't really matter if copies are reflinked, hardlinked or independent. You want them all gone, right?

You concentrated on detecting reflinked files, maybe because you know other possibilities don't occur in your case; and you probably hope an approach specific to reflinks in Btrfs will be quicker than a general one. Possible problems:

- The approach will probably not be quicker¹. Compare to [detecting hardlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73538/108618), where you need to examine all files and match the inode. To detect reflinks you probably need to examine all files and match blocks used. Different abstraction layer and even more work.
- Sharing blocks is not all-or-nothing. Files may be reflinked partially. Various scenarios are possible. Some of them are common (can occur after making a snapshot or a CoW-copy), some are less common (e.g. they require `duperemove` or similar on-demand tool which you may have never used). Assuming the file in question consists of `[block1][block2]`, these are few examples:

  - Another file is `[block1]` or `[block1][block3]`. Conclusion: it's not enough to find one shared block; you need to check all blocks of the "original".
  - There are files `[block1][block3]` and `[block4][block2]` (but no other file that is exactly `[block1][block2]`). Conclusion: even if you know all blocks of the "original" are shared, you cannot be sure a "copy" exists; you need to check if they are all shared within a certain "copy".
  - The other file may be `[block2][block1]`. Conclusion: the above is not enough; you need to check if blocks in the "copy" are in the right sequence.

    - But if `[block1]` and `[block2]` contain the same data (by accident or whatever) then `[block1][block2]` and `[block2][block1]` are identical *and* they occupy the same space. Conclusion: "wrong sequence" and "right sequence" may be virtually equivalent.
  - The other file may be `[block1][block2][block5]`. Conclusion: it's not enough to find all blocks of the "original" and in the right sequence; you need to examine the alleged "copy" more closely.

For these reasons you should consider an approach based solely on the content, unless you want to find reflinked copies *only* (i.e. you *deliberately want to ignore* other copies if they exist).

It seems it's easy to find (by googling or so) ways to "find duplicates", but not so easy to find ways to "find duplicates of a *specific file*". I mean common answers concentrate on finding all sets of duplicates within one or more directories ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277697/108618)). The point is any set reported may or may not include the file in question. I haven't tested all possible tools, some of them may provide a way to compare strictly to the file you want, instead of "for every potential pair".

If a tool does not provide such way, it may at least provide a way to include/exclude files according to their size. This may greatly reduce the set of "all potential pairs", but a set of duplicates that doesn't include the file in question can still occur.

I think I may be able to write a general-purpose script that finds duplicates of a given file by its content and does it reasonably fast. Since the question concentrates on reflinks in Btrfs, I don't think this answer is a right place for such script².

---

¹) I admit I haven't tested because I don't know such approach. If I knew, I would place it in the answer because this is what you explicitly asked for.

²) You (or anyone) can ask a separate general question that will be the right place. Or maybe you manage to find an already existing question. Leave me a comment under this answer to lure me to the other place.

Comment: I want to remove all copies of the target files, no matter how they are duplicated, but only if they are an exact, unmodified, copy. I edited the question so it doesn't fall into XY problem.